# Hovering effect over image link is overextending the div it is surrounded in

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

So for some reason when I hover over specific points below an image link I have that is wrapped in a div, it will trigger the hovering effect for the image link that I have created through CSS. I have tried multiple things (overflow:hidden, display:inline-block) but nothing seems to work. I will post my code and a jsfiddle link. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="div_for_projects">
 <div class="project_inner_divs">
  <div id="portfolio_project">
    <div id="portfolio_project_child">
      <a href="index.html">
        <!--
        Image Source:
        http://www.connectwithchildlife.com/2015/10/child-life-portfolio.html
        -->
        <img class="portfolio_page_projects"
        src="http://www.vandelaydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/portfolio2.jpg"
        alt="portfolio_image">
      </a>
      <p>
        <a href="index.html"
        class="text_align project_description">
          PROJECT
        </a>
      </p>
      <a href="#">
        <img class="portfolio_sm_links"
        src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Editing//arrow_filled1600.png"
        alt="Portfolio Image Link">
      </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div_for_projects {
  width: 100%;
  height: 420px;
}
.project_inner_divs {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}
#portfolio_project {
  position: relative;
  width: 426px;
  height: 420px;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
#portfolio_project_child {
  pointer-events: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#portfolio_project:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
}
#portfolio_project:hover .project_description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
#portfolio_project:hover .portfolio_sm_links {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.portfolio_page_projects {
  width: 426px;
  height: 420px;
}
.project_description {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  display: inline-block;
  left: 170px;
 }
.text_align {
  text-align: center;
}
.portfolio_sm_links {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 130px;
  left: 350px;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
.portfolio_sm_links:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/26vutwz9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nested `<p>` is part of the div you are checking for the `hover` so its size is included. If you can move the `<p>` outside of the `<div id="portfolio_project_child">` or its parent it will solve the problem (but introduce others).

```
<div class="div_for_projects">
 <div class="project_inner_divs">
  <div id="portfolio_project">
    <div id="portfolio_project_child">
      <a href="index.html">
        <!--
        Image Source:
        http://www.connectwithchildlife.com/2015/10/child-life-portfolio.html
        -->
        <img class="portfolio_page_projects"
        src="http://www.vandelaydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/portfolio2.jpg"
        alt="portfolio_image">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img class="portfolio_sm_links"
        src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Share/icon/Editing//arrow_filled1600.png"
        alt="Portfolio Image Link">
      </a>
   </div>
   <p>
     <a href="index.html"
      class="text_align project_description">
      PROJECT
     </a>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/26vutwz9/1/

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I was able to fix the other issue that was introduced by adding a margin to one of my links and for some reason that fixed it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph tag is your issue. You can solve it by taking it out of the normal html flow with a position absolute, like

```
#portfolio_project_child p { position: absolute; top: 0; left:0 }
```